# Can't scrape .aspx sites

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to scrape numerous companies sites in Python for their news releases.

I figured out I need to use `chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'lxml')`  instead of `chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'html.parser')`  for aspx sites. I am still getting the basic urls back like their contact and careers links instead of the actual news article links. When I inspect the website it looks something like:

`<a class="module_headline-link" href="/news-and-events/news/news-details/2022/Compugen-to-Release-Second-Quarter-Results-on-Thursday-August-4-2022/default.aspx">Compugen to Release Second Quarter Results on Thursday, August 4, 2022</a>`.

On the basic html sites it works to print all of `my_links` and I can filter which link by the hashed out lines. I thought I'd add a few examples of troubled scrapes and one of a working one. I assume the not working ones are the same problem and probably due to not understanding the intricacies of lxml. I just assume it can't see the articles for some reason (unlike the html) because they start with `/`. Thanks for any help.

COMPANY 1-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://ir.cgen.com/news-and-events/news/default.aspx'
full = ''


html_text = requests.get(URL).text
chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'lxml')
    

for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
    my_links = (link.get('href'))
    print(my_links)
    #if str(my_links).startswith("/news-and-events/news/news-details/"):
     #   print(str(full)+my_links)
    #else:
     #   None
```

COMPANY 2-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.meipharma.com/media/press-releases'
full = ''


html_text = requests.get(URL).text
chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'html.parser')
    

for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
    my_links = (link.get('href'))
    print(my_links)
#    if str(my_links).startswith(""):
 #       print(str(full)+my_links)
  #  else:
   #     None
```

COMPANY 3-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://investor.sierraoncology.com/news-releases/default.aspx'
full = ''


html_text = requests.get(URL).text
chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'lxml')
    

for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
    my_links = (link.get('href'))
    print(my_links)
```

VS html site that works for my purposes

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://investors.aileronrx.com/index.php/news-releases"
full = "https://investors.aileronrx.com"

ALRNlinks = []

html_text = requests.get(URL).text
chickennoodle = soup(html_text, 'html.parser')

for link in chickennoodle.find_all('a'):
    my_links = (link.get('href'))
    if str(my_links).startswith("/news-rele"):
        ALRN = (str(full)+my_links)
        ALRNlinks.append(ALRN)
        print(ALRNlinks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The website from your first example is loading information dynamically in page, so requests won't see the information pulled by javascript, after the page loaded. You can however look into Dev Tools - network tab, and see which urls are being accessed by javascript, and try and scrape those. For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ir.cgen.com/feed/PressRelease.svc/GetPressReleaseList?LanguageId=1&bodyType=0&pressReleaseDateFilter=3&categoryId=1cb807d2-208f-4bc3-9133-6a9ad45ac3b0&pageSize=-1&pageNumber=0&tagList=&includeTags=true&year=2022&excludeSelection=1'
r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['GetPressReleaseListResult'])
print(df)
```

This will print out:

```
Attachments Body    Category    DocumentFileSize    DocumentFileType    DocumentPath    ExcludeFromLatest   Headline    LanguageId  LinkToDetailPage    ... RevisionNumber  SeoName ShortBody   ShortDescription    Subheadline SubheadlineHtml TagsList    ThumbnailPath   WorkflowId  PressReleaseDate
0   []  None            PDF https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   False   Compugen to Release Second Quarter Results on ...   1   /news-and-events/news/news-details/2022/Compug...   ... 33221   Compugen-to-Release-Second-Quarter-Results-on-...   None        None    None    []  https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   e7b13fbb-ddc7-4955-a9c6-b44e6ab223ec    07/21/2022 07:00:00
1   []  None            PDF https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   False   Compugen to Present at Upcoming Industry Confe...   1   /news-and-events/news/news-details/2022/Compug...   ... 33213   Compugen-to-Present-at-Upcoming-Industry-Confe...   None        None    None    []  https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   1e5cb121-a9f7-4e1b-86c1-1571065d40b5    06/27/2022 07:00:00
2   []  None            PDF https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   False   Compugen to Present at Upcoming Investor Confe...   1   /news-and-events/news/news-details/2022/Compug...   ... 33202   Compugen-to-Present-at-Upcoming-Investor-Confe...   None        None    None    []  https://s26.q4cdn.com/977440944/files/doc_news...   8c004950-09c8-4831-bdfa-25f660afe250    06/01/2022 07:00:00
[...]
```

You  can apply this for your other examples as well.